# Wieferich primes in base $47$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Wieferich primes are defined as prime numbers $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $2^{p − 1} − 1$. While reading about such primes, I came upon the following curious conjecture on the [Wikipedia page of "unsolved problems in number theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Number_theory):

> Are there any Wieferich primes in base $47$?

Since no explanation is given for this strange question, I find myself puzzled by the importance of the number $47$ within this context. What role does this base in particular have in the context of Wieferich primes and why would it be important to solve this problem in particular, instead of another number base?

Comment: Perhaps someone looked, and found Wieferich primes in all other small bases.

Comment: In fact, $47$ is the smallest base without a known example.

Comment: What does the base even have to do with it?

Comment: See [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime#Base-a_Wieferich_primes)

Comment: Yup, just found the relevant bit in the wikipedia article. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Wieferich only demonstrated properites relating to the binary sevenites: ie 1093 and 3511.  There are Marianoff primes, or trinary sevenites, and Shanks primes (decimal sevenites), and a number of others.  No general name exists for this class.

Comment: It has two weiferich primes in this dodgie defintion.  Both eminately accessable with mental calculations.

Comment: This is often called "generalized Wieferich primes" and the "base" *b* is meant as $b^p-1$ generalizing from $b=2$. So $3^5-1 = 2 \cdot 11^2$ and thus $5$ is a "generalized Wieferich prime" to base $b=3$ (the common name for those is "Mirimanoff primes"). You find more about this by the keyword "high orders of fermat-quotients" and so. One (amateurish) discussion of mine you can find here: http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf and have an index of links http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotient/directory/index.htm (I didn't find gen.wief.primes base $b=47$ btw.)

Comment: ... upps, in my previous comment it is of course" $3^5-1 = 2 \cdot 11^2$ and thus $11$ is a 'generalized Wieferich-prime' to base $b=3$". Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the internet, it indeed seems that **Peter** was right in the comment section, and $47$ is the *smallest base for which no Wieferich primes are known*.

Answer (score -4):

Weiferich primes exist only in base 2. He wrote his paper in 1908, but the question has been around since the time of Euler.  Dickson's history of mathematics devotes 12 pages to this question, but affords Weiferich only five lines in a paragraph on the nineth page.  It is misleading to use this term.

Weiferich did not discover sevenites, but he noted that a particular solution to fermat's last proposition exists only for binary sevenites.

There is no particular reason for 47 not to have any particular sevenites.  A similar situation exists with there being no known iso-sevenites for 3, (the Fibonacci series) which means that no instance of where if $p \mid F_n$ then also $p^2 \mid F_n$.  However, the octagon-series and the Heron series, which correspond to isobases 6 and 4, do have sevenites.

Thus, in the series of Heron triangles, (triangles of sides e-1, e, e+1 and integer area), if 103 divides a side, so does $103^2$.

47 has 2 as a sevenite (or 'weiferich prime').  The two-place period of 2 supposes only 8, as can be seen in 11, 13 and 45.  Here 32 divides 47^2-1, and thus it has two as a sevenite.

EDIT:

The table of 'sevenites' for particular bases, up to b=14400 and p=2000000, do not produce a list of primes longer than 80 digits, except in one or two cases.  The number is quite small.  Sort of in the $\sum 1/p$ range.  There are a good scattering of unfilled rows, 47 is the first.

In the early versions of the tables I produced 6 was the first unfilled row.  But then 61661 came along.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/988445)

Comment: It actually does.  The iteration beginning 2,b, and continuing t(n+1)=b.t(n)-t(n-1), is a very base-like structure, and the distribution of p²|t(p)-b, is identical to that if p²|b^p-b.  The example of b=3 gives the lucas numbers.

Comment: I have not been able to find any reference to the general class of sevenite being called Weiferich numbers, until i posted these as sevenites on the dozenal list as an entity, and D.S. reusing the name 'Weiferich' as a general name.  I stick by my name.

Comment: 11 is a Wieferich prime base 3 because 3^10 = 1 modulo 11^2, so they CAN exists in other bases not 2

Comment: @J.Linne  The two wieferich primes are 1093 and 3511.  In base 3, this is 1111111 and 11211001.  Sevenites in base 3, such as 11, are Marianoff primes.  Decimal sevenites such as 3 and 487 are Shanks Primes.  I studied the thing back in the eighties, when the general member had no name.  I called them sevenites.

Comment: On the other hand, 2 is a 'weiferich prime' for this base.  Since the two-place period produces only eight, anything past eight gives a weiferich prime, viz 47^2-1 = 32*69, but as only eight is expected (see, eg 11 or 13), the rest are due to sevenites.