# How far was base $47$ checked for a generalized Wieferich-prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

This question is closely related to :

[Wieferich primes in base $47$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721770/wieferich-primes-in-base-47)

but I would like to know the current search limit for this base.

> Upto which prime $p$ was $$47^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p^2$$ verified ?

Wikipedia only says that no solution is known, but for this particular base I could not find a search limit.

Comment: [Here](http://fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermQ_Sorg.txt) has a list for Wieferich primes of base up to $10125$ and it looks like they have searched up to $1.202E+12$. Also, [here](http://fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermQ_Sort.txt) lists all the primes of base up to $1052$ and according to Google Translate, for base that has all prime factors smaller than 61, search limit is $9.3E+13$; for base whose largest prime factor is between $67$ and $149$, search limit is $5.58E+13$; for the remaining bases, search limit is $1.202E+13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link posted in the comments suggests the following (translated from German):

- The bases that have a maximum prime divisor up to $61$ are verified until $9.8 \times 10^{13}$,
- The bases that have a maximum prime divisor from $67$ up to $149$ are verified until $6.01 \times 10^{13}$,
- The rest is verified until $1.202\times10^{13}$.

So it seems that the answer to your question is

> *Up to $9.8 \times 10^{13}$.*